# Mapstruct uses not working, how to make mapstruct "uses" use other mapper for inner fields

Tags: java, maven, mapstruct, annotation-processing, mapper

Mapstruct "uses" not working, it maps all entities in one mapper, instead of using different mappers for different entities
I have pom

```
`<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${compiler.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>17</source>
                <target>17</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                        <version>0.2.0</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>`
```

```
@Mapper(uses = {ParticipantMapper.class})
public interface RoomMapper {

    RoomMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(RoomMapper.class);

    @Mapping(target = "participant", source = "participant")
    RoomFullDto entityToData(RoomEntity entity);

    @Mapping(target = "participant", source = "participant")
    RoomEntity dataToEntity(RoomFullDto entity);

    @Named("EntityToShortData")
    RoomShortDto entityToShortData(RoomEntity entity);

    @Named("DataToEntity")
    RoomEntity shortDataToEntity(RoomShortDto entity);
}
```

and

```
@Mapper
public interface ParticipantMapper {


    ParticipantMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(ParticipantMapper.class);

    @Named("DataToEntity")
    @Mapping(target = "room.id", source = "roomId")
    @Mapping(target = "user.id", source = "userId")
    @Mapping(target = "nicknameInRoom", source = "username")
    ParticipantEntity dtoToEntity (ParticipantDto participantDto);

    @Named("EntityToData")
    @Mapping(target = "roomId", source = "room.id")
    @Mapping(target = "userId", source = "user.id")
    @Mapping(target = "username", source = "nicknameInRoom")
    ParticipantDto entityToDto (ParticipantEntity participantDto);
}
```

in RoomMapperImpl mapstruct generate without using ParticipantMapper, so i cant't configure how to map fields and it ignores some fields

```
public RoomFullDto entityToData(RoomEntity entity) {
        if ( entity == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        RoomFullDto roomFullDto = new RoomFullDto();

        roomFullDto.setParticipant( participantEntitySetToParticipantDtoList( entity.getParticipant() ) );
        roomFullDto.setId( entity.getId() );
        roomFullDto.setName( entity.getName() );

        return roomFullDto;
    }

protected List<ParticipantDto> participantEntitySetToParticipantDtoList(Set<ParticipantEntity> set) {
        if ( set == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<ParticipantDto> list = new ArrayList<ParticipantDto>( set.size() );
        for ( ParticipantEntity participantEntity : set ) {
            list.add( participantEntityToParticipantDto( participantEntity ) );
        }

        return list;
    }

ParticipantDto participantEntityToParticipantDto(ParticipantEntity participantEntity) {
        if ( participantEntity == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        ParticipantDto participantDto = new ParticipantDto();

        participantDto.setId( participantEntity.getId() );
        participantDto.setIsBanned( participantEntity.getIsBanned() );
        if ( participantEntity.getRole() != null ) {
            participantDto.setRole( participantEntity.getRole().name() );
        }

        return participantDto;
    }
```

I tried to configure different versions of dependencies and annotationProcessors, it dont works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RoomFullDto#participant` field type is `java.util.List<ParticipantDto>` (not `ParticipantDto`)

The `ParticipantEntity#participant` field type `is java.util.Set<ParticipantEntity>` (not `ParticipantEntity`)

We need to declare the mapping process between two **different types**: `Set<ParticipantEntity>` and `List<ParticipantDto>`

1. `Set<ParticipantEntity>` -> `List<ParticipantDto>` transformation
2. `List<ParticipantDto>` -> `Set<ParticipantEntity>` transformation

### Please try to add 2 more methods for ParticipantMapper.java:

Create a new method ParticipantMapper#mapToList:

```
@Mapper
public interface ParticipantMapper {
  

    ParticipantMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(ParticipantMapper.class);

    @Named("DataToEntity")
    @Mapping(target = "room.id", source = "roomId")
    @Mapping(target = "user.id", source = "userId")
    @Mapping(target = "nicknameInRoom", source = "username")
    ParticipantEntity dtoToEntity (ParticipantDto participantDto);

    @Named("EntityToData")
    @Mapping(target = "roomId", source = "room.id")
    @Mapping(target = "userId", source = "user.id")
    @Mapping(target = "username", source = "nicknameInRoom")
    ParticipantDto entityToDto (ParticipantEntity participantDto);
  

    //+ 2 additional mapping methods without any annota
    List<ParticipantDto> mapToDtoList(Set<ParticipantEntity> set);

    Set<ParticipantEntity> mapToEntitySet(List<ParticipantDto> list);
}
```

[MapStruct Documentation: 6. Mapping collections](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-collections)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Made a slightly versatile  ` List<ParticipantDto> mapToDtoList(Collection<ParticipantEntity> set);

    Set<ParticipantEntity> mapToEntitySet(Collection<ParticipantDto> list);`